# How to wrap exception on exhausted retries with Spring Retry

Tags: spring-retry

**Context:**

I'm using spring-retry to retry restTemplate calls.

The restTemplate calls are called from a kafka listener.
The kafka listener is also configured to retry on error (if any exception are thrown during the process, not only the restTemplate call).

**Goal:**

I'd like to prevent kafka from retrying when the error come from a retry template which has exhausted.

**Actual behavior :**

When the retryTemplate exhaust all retries, the original exception is thrown. Thus preventing me from identifying if the error was retried by the retryTemplate.

**Desired behavior:**

When the retryTemplate exhaust all retries, wrap the original exception in a RetryExhaustedException which will allow me to blacklist it from kafka retries.

**Question:**

How can I do something like this ?

Thanks

**Edit**

RetryTemplate configuration :

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
retryableExceptions.put(FunctionalException.class, false);
SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, retryableExceptions, true, true);
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

retryTemplate.setThrowLastExceptionOnExhausted(false);
```

Kafka ErrorHandler

```
public class DefaultErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

@Override
public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> data) {
    Throwable exception = Optional.ofNullable(thrownException.getCause()).orElse(thrownException);

    // TODO if exception as been retried in a RetryTemplate, stop it to prevent rollback and send it to a DLQ
    // else rethrow exception, it will be rollback and handled by AfterRollbackProcessor to be retried
    throw new KafkaException("Could not handle exception", thrownException);
   }
}
```

Listener kafka :

```
@KafkaListener
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    retryTemplate.execute((args) -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Should be catched by ErrorHandler to prevent rollback");
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Should be retried by afterRollbackProcessor");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply configure the listener retry template with a `SimplyRetryPolicy` that is configured to classify `RetryExhaustedException` as not retryable.

Be sure to set the `traverseCauses` property to true since the container wraps all listener exceptions in `ListenerExecutionFailedException`.

```
/**
 * Create a {@link SimpleRetryPolicy} with the specified number of retry
 * attempts. If traverseCauses is true, the exception causes will be traversed until
 * a match is found. The default value indicates whether to retry or not for exceptions
 * (or super classes) are not found in the map.
 *
 * @param maxAttempts the maximum number of attempts
 * @param retryableExceptions the map of exceptions that are retryable based on the
 * map value (true/false).
 * @param traverseCauses is this clause traversable
 * @param defaultValue the default action.
 */
public SimpleRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts, Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions,
        boolean traverseCauses, boolean defaultValue) {
```

**EDIT**

Use

```
template.execute((args) -> {...}, (context) -> throw new Blah(context.getLastThrowable()));
```

Comment: I already configured the SimpleRetryPolicy with traverseCauses to true. But this is throwing the original exception which is then wrapped in LEFE. What I want is a RetryExhaustedException to be fired, not the original exception. Which will allow me to do if (thrownException instanceof RetryExhaustedException) in the ErrorHandler

Comment: You need to edit the question and show your code - there is no way the container will strip your `RetryExhaustedException` from the top of the chain - it knows nothing about listener exceptions. I am assuming you are throwing that from your recovery callback. If there is no recovery callback, the template throws an `ExhaustedRetryException` wrapping your original exception, unless you have set `throwLastExceptionOnExhausted` to true, which will cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: Edited my question, but throwLastExceptionOnExhausted is not used since state is null in RetryTemplate class

Comment: Ah - got it; sorry; in that case you should add a recovery callback in your `execute()` and throw your wrapper there. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Note that, if needed, you can pass arbitrary information from the `RetryCallback` to the `RecoveryCallback` using `context.setAttribute(...);`.

Comment: If I want it to be generic, can I throw an exception in a RetryListener on close method if throwable  != null ? Instead of adding callback to every execute ?

Comment: It looks like it should work - I don't see any protection in the template when calling the listeners.

Comment: I mean is it a good practice ? Or it might fail in future updates ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "good practice". Maybe the better long term solution would be to open a new feature request for spring-retry to add a property to enable throwing `ExhaustedRetryException` even when there is no state (and no recovery callback). Contributions are welcome over there.